# C# - cannot convert from double to [variable name]

Tags: c#, class, xaml, type-conversion

I'm implementing LU decomposition in C#. In `MainWindow.xaml.cs` I read matrix elements from the form, convert them into double, and use the `LowerUpper.cs` class and its functions (edited out for easier reading) for calculation. This is the problem segment:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace NM1test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Compute()
        {
            double A11 = Convert.ToDouble(a11.Text);
            double A12 = Convert.ToDouble(a12.Text);
            double A13 = Convert.ToDouble(a13.Text);

            double A21 = Convert.ToDouble(a21.Text);
            double A22 = Convert.ToDouble(a22.Text);
            double A23 = Convert.ToDouble(a23.Text);

            double A31 = Convert.ToDouble(a31.Text);
            double A32 = Convert.ToDouble(a32.Text);
            double A33 = Convert.ToDouble(a33.Text);

            LowerUpper lu = new LowerUpper(A11, A12, A13, A21, A22, A23, A31, A32, A33);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Compute();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I found similar inquiries but they were mostly about mismatched variable types, typos, or using `Convert.ToDouble` wrong. I'm sure none of that is the case. I don't see why A11 is somehow a type? Those are perfectly normal functional doubles.

I also have an error in `LowerUpper.cs` when declaring `LowerUpper()`: "The type or namespace 'A11' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace NM1test
{
    class LowerUpper
    {
        public LowerUpper(A11, A12, A13, A21, A22, A23, A31, A32, A33)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I don't have lots of experience with Visual Studio projects so these errors are really confusing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `double.TryParse`?

Comment: The parameters for the constructor for LowerUpper don't follow "type" space "name", so it assumes you're missing the parameter name rather than the parameter type.  It also wouldn't know what types A11, A12, etc. are, but that a separate error.  You need to specify "public LowerUpper(double A11, double A12, ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you have this error is that you forgot to specify the types of the arguments in the `LowerUpper` constructor. That's why Visual Studio thinks that `A11`-`A33` are types.

Your `LowerUpper` class should look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace NM1test
{
    class LowerUpper
    {
        public LowerUpper(double A11, double A12, double A13, double A21, double A22, double A23, double A31, double A32, double A33)
        {
            // initialization code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked! what an awkward mistake... I completely forgot that's even a thing lol. thank you very much ^-^